# Allow user to select image to share

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Is it possible to allow the user to select image from a list of selection before sharing it on their Facebook page without asking for permission? I'm referring to the current Facebook API which v2.5.

I tried using Feed dialog, but it only allow one image at one time.

So, the workflow would be:

1. User open web page
2. User click share on FB
3. User select an image from the selections
4. Share

I know if I copy paste the link, I can select which image I want to show with the multiple `og:image` tag, but right now, I want the user to click the share button on my website.

Current code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://.ngrok.com/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-green.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-orange.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-cat-1.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-cat-2.png" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-cat-3.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://.ngrok.com/avatar-cat-4.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Meh" />
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      function feed() {
        FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://.ngrok.com/',
          name: 'Name',
          description: 'Description',
          caption: 'Caption',
        }, function(response){ if (response != null) { alert('shared') } });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Meh
      <a href="#" onclick="feed()">Feed</a>
    </p>
    <div
      class="fb-like"
      data-share="true"
      data-width="450"
      data-show-faces="true">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want them to click a specific image, and share that particular image?

Comment: It'd be better if I can somehow make the feed or share dialog support multiple images so that the flow would be seamless.

Comment: _“I tried using Feed dialog, but it only allow one image at one time”_ – well then create a little UI for the user to chose an image _before_ you call the Feed dialog – and then pass the address of the chosen image to the dialog.

Comment: Done that, was looking for answer whether it's possible to do it without extra  little UI. But I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple images using the Open Graph meta tags, and that will give the user the option to cycle through several images and select one.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Image+1" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Image+2" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Image+3" />
```

Comment: I think (and I've tried) that a user can only cycle the images if he copy and pastes the link into his profile but not when he clicked the share button (displays only one image).

Comment: If Facebook cached your page before you added the additional image options you may need to refresh the cache. You can do that by going to the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and entering the URL of your page. That should refresh the cache and index the new image options.

Comment: I've done that too. As I said, I can cycle the images when copy pasting, but not when clicking the share button.

Comment: You can use the `sharer.php` URL to take the user to Facebook and use the web interface using a link with an `href` of `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=YOUR-URL-HERE`

Comment: Just tried it. Even the `sharer.php` is using the same UI as the `share` dialog which doesn't allow me to choose image.

Comment: Code added. It's alive for now